# Table sorter width 100% does not work if table is contained into others tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, tablesorter

I use tablesorter (https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter), with widget scroller.

You can find examples here : http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-scroller.html

My problem is when tablesorter is contained into other tables like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            table sorter table
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

table sorter does not take 100% of the width... And the horizontal scrollbar does not appear automatically.

You can find a example here : http://jsfiddle.net/oqfq47fc/8/

Whereas if table sorter is not contained in other table, its works...

You can find a example here : http://jsfiddle.net/oqfq47fc/9/

Can you help me? I works in portal context and contents portlets are inside table, and it is not possible to remove nested tables.

I think it's just a matter of css, but I know no more...

**EDIT**

I need that table takes 100% of width like this picture :

[image]

And when I resize the browser and that the all table can not display in the available space, a horizontal scrollbar appear at the bottom of the table like this picture :

[image]

It works good in my first example.

But in my second example with the outer table, the table look like this picture :

[image]

And when I resize the browser, the horizontal scroll bar does not appear on table but on window like this picture :

[image]

Comment: deleting old comment cause looking at it doesn't make as much sense when I first wrote it... Do you have the table set to 100% width in your css??

Comment: If a set table width to 100%, no change... You can try it here http://jsfiddle.net/oqfq47fc/8/ If I remove parent table its works, but if table is contained in other table, it doesn't work

Comment: Yea looking at that hasn't helped me sadly. Can you provide an image of what you need it to be or some better explanation of what you're wanting?

Comment: @CayceK. I answer my post. It is clearer?

Answer (score 2):

```
table{
    display: block;
     max-width: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
        width: 100%;
}

table.data-table,table#tvar_1{
    display: table;
}

html{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.tablesorter-scroller-table{
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oqfq47fc/12/)

Adding this set of code is as close as I can get to reproducing what you want with strictly tables. You are using tables for layout and you really shouldn't be doing that. The best way to go is to use the div the way you are in the second iteration where it is correct. It obviously displays the correct and best way. Also, with what I had to do to these tables it is not nice.

Do your best to avoid tables where tables are not needed. This is tabular data so it is needed, but using a table to construct the page is not the right way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try with your proposal. I work in portal context (WebSphere) and I have not hands on layout... If I could, I suppressed all tables for layout.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense on that. I hope this works for you then. Portals are hard to work around, but it is worth it sometimes.